# EXCEL: How to get sumproduct of two columns that is filterable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, epplus

I have two different sheets in one workbook. One has the allotted time by month for each resource and the other has the rates by month for each resource.

I am using this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Test!F2:F12,Rates!C2:C12)
```

This gets me the total monthly value for each row multiplied by the corresponding rate on the other worksheet.

What I'm trying to do is make the total dynamic when I use the filters.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a sample of the data in the sheets and columns your formula refers to.

Comment: The worksheet structure doesn't make much sense. With allotted time in your Test worksheet's column F you would need a row-by-row relationship with the Rates worksheet; this would be better as an additional column on the Test worksheet, possibly with a lookup (many to one) to the Rates worksheet. Follow the suggestion by @hamish and provide some data to illustrate your problem.